# Phonegap iOS keyboard hide for full application

Tags: ios, cordova

We are developing application where all inputs are taken from barcode scanner and we never want iOS keyboard to pop-up for input. Is there any native code we can add it as plug-in?

We are using phonegap to compile html5 app to iOS platform.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Link1](http://uihacker.blogspot.in/2011/10/javascript-hide-ios-soft-keyboard.html) [Link2](http://petercorvers.nl/phonegapcordova-hide-ios-keyboard/)

> The 2nd line will de-focus all input fields, and it relies on jQuery. I found that calling blur() on the single focused textfield didn't always work. Either one of these lines should work independently, but both of them together cannot be stopped!

```
var hideKeyboard = function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();
};
```